# How can i read a HTML file and display the content in GWT with its css

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I just want to read a HTML file and display its content in a GWT widget. Already I have done it but i'm not getting its css and javascripts. So can anyone help me to get the content with its css and javascripts?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Frame-Widget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html)

> A widget that wraps an IFRAME element, which can contain an arbitrary web site.

Usage (taken from the doc):

```
public class FrameExample implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Make a new frame, and point it at Google.
    Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.google.com/");

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get().add(frame);
   }
}
```

Comment: Chris,

I tried the same. I got a rectangular box. But I don't get the expexted result. Can you help me?


Thanks in advance,
Gnik